# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, jupyter-lab, permissionerror

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1472\299081128.py in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import csv
----> 4 train_df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Satishrao\Desktop\Major Project',nrows=200)
      5 test_df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Satishrao\Desktop\Major Project')
      6 print (train_df.shape)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    686     )
    687 
--> 688     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    689 
    690 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    452 
    453     # Create the parser.
--> 454     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    455 
    456     if chunksize or iterator:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    946             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    947 
--> 948         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    949 
    950     def close(self):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1178     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1179         if engine == "c":
-> 1180             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1181         else:
   1182             if engine == "python":
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Satishrao\\Desktop\\Major Project'

​
```

I tried enabling the permissions where I have observed it is okay but still when I executed it getting the same error, can any one resolve this issue ??

Comment: You're trying to read what I assume are folders as a CSV file. You have to put the full name of the file there - `train_df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Satishrao\Desktop\Major Project\train.csv',nrows=200)` for example. If `Major Project` is the name of the CSV file, then do `train_df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Satishrao\Desktop\Major Project.csv',nrows=200)`, or whatever the file's extension is. Please note that you need to change the next line as well.

Comment: @MattDMo is right. line 688 of parsers.py in your error shows that it is expecting a `filepath` which can only account for file-like objects that have a read() method.
Change the path to include the filename.
Also, pandas discourages opening the same file twice and since you have tried opening the same path for both test and train, that may not work.